# How to prevent overriding in array?

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to add all the keys of different json available in a file to an array. What I did for the moment is this:

```
  //Get the json file content
  $jsonData = file(__DIR__ .'/../logs/error.json');

  //Save all the json
  $json = [];

  //Iterate through the line of the file, each line is a json
  foreach($jsonData as $line)
  {
    //Convert the json in an associative array
    $array = json_decode($line, true);

    //Iterate through the json keys
    foreach($array as $k => $val)
    {
      $json[$k] = $val;
    }
  }
```

the json file is like this:

```
{"Timestamp":"2018-06-14T10:46:52.3326036+02:00","Level":"Error","MessageTemplate":"System.Exception"}
{"Timestamp":"2018-06-14T10:47:22.7493871+02:00","Level":"Error","MessageTemplate":"System.Exception"}
```

I'll get this:

```
{"Timestamp":"2018-06-14T10:47:22.7493871+02:00","Level":"Error","MessageTemplate":"System.Exception"}
```

because the `$json[$k]` override I guess the previous array, but `$k` is a new `json` so why the index of the array is replaced?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be this one is your expected output.

```
//Get the json file content
  $jsonData = file(__DIR__ .'/../logs/error.json');

  //Save all the json
  $json = [];

  //Iterate through the line of the file, each line is a json
  foreach($jsonData as $line)
  {
    //Convert the json in an associative array
    $array = json_decode($line, true);

    $temp = [];
    //Iterate through the json keys
    foreach($array as $k => $val)
    {
      $temp[$k] = $val;
    }
    $json[] = $temp;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

change this line

```
foreach($array as $k => $val)
    {
      $json[$k] = $val;
    }
```

to

```
foreach($array as $k => $val)
    {
      $json[][$k] = $val;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you're overwriting keys with the same names, so there's really nothing surprising in your output.

You probably meant to do this:

```
foreach($jsonData as $line) {
    $tmp = []; //<-- set up a new array just for this iteration
    $array = json_decode($line, true);
    foreach($array as $k => $val) $tmp[$k] = $val;
    $json[] = $tmp; //<-- log the array in the master $json array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
//Get the json file content

  $jsonData = file(__DIR__ .'/../logs/error.json');
  
//Convert the json in an associative array

  $array = json_decode($jsonData, true);
  
//Save all the json

  $json = [];

  //Iterate through the line of the file, each line is a json

  foreach($array as $k => $val)
  {

    $json[][$k] = $val;
    
  }
```